# There is no Action mapped for action name testAction

Tags: jsp, struts2

I made my first struts2 application and after I tried to launch it I have the following error:

**There is no Action mapped for action name testAction.**

If the namespace is correct, what is the problem?

`struts.xml` are locate in `src` folder

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/home/jsp/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="testAction" class="com.myapp.common.action.TestAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
     </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Which URL are you calling, *exactly* ?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/Struts2Ex/home/jsp/testAction.action

Comment: Try with `namespace="/home/jsp"`, without the latest slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<package name="default" namespace="/home/jsp" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="testAction" class="com.myapp.common.action.TestAction">
        <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
    </action>
 </package>
```